# How to Upload Files on ReactiveForms in Angular to Nest.js Service

Tags: angular, file-upload, nestjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have a modal-dialog with a reactive form where I want to upload a file/image.

dialog.html

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div>
      <mat-label>Hintergrund</mat-label>
      <input formControlName="file" id="file" type="file" class="form-control" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
      <div *ngIf="f.file.touched && f.file.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="f.file.errors.required">Hintergrund wird benötigt</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput id="name" formControlName="name" required />
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="actions">
      <button mat-raised-button color="default" type="button" (click)="onCancel()">Abbrechen</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="button">Speichern</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

dialog.ts

```
export class GenerateAdComponent implements AfterContentChecked {

    formGroup: FormGroup;
    shellScriptConfig = environment.adGenerator.instagram_sh;

    constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: EventDto,
        private readonly dialog: MatDialogRef<GenerateAdComponent, InstaAdData>,
        private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            config: new FormControl(this.shellScriptConfig),
            file: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            fileSource: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            name: new FormControl(this.data.name)
        });
    }

    get f() {
        return this.formGroup.controls;
    }

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }

    onCancel(): void {
        this.dialog.close();
    }

    onSubmit(): void {
        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        const instaAdData: InstaAdData = {
            file: this.formGroup.get('fileSource').value,
            name: this.formGroup.get('name').value,
            config: this.formGroup.get('config').value
        };

        this.dialog.close(instaAdData);
    }

    onFileChange(event: any) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            this.formGroup.patchValue({
                fileSource: file
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This dialog is triggered by the following component:

component.ts (shortened)

```
async openGenerateAdDialog(element: EventDto): Promise<void> {
    const ref = this.matDialog.open<GenerateAdComponent, EventDto, InstaAdData>(GenerateAdComponent, {
      data: element
    });

    const result = await ref.afterClosed().toPromise();

    if (!!result) {
      console.log('RESULT: ', result); // <= here
      await this.adService.addAd(result).toPromise();
    }
  }
```

When I log out here, I get valid data for file -> i.e.

output of console.log

```
config: {shellScript: "./advertisement_instagram.sh", topLayer: "./assets/images/rahmen.png", textFields: {…}}
file: File {name: "some.tif", lastModified: 1427320884000, lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 25 2015 23:01:24 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2088876, …}
name: "fnddghmm"
```

But in my Nest.js Service the data for file is missing:

```
{
  file: {},
  name: 'fnddghmm',
  config: {
    shellScript: './advertisement_instagram.sh',
    topLayer: './assets/images/rahmen.png',
    textFields: {
      eventName: 142,
      price: 298,
      weekday: 142,
      date: 142,
      timeWindow: 142
    }
  }
```

I expected the source of the file, for writing it into the filesystem. How can I achieve that?

This is how I transport my data from the angular-client to nest.js service:

```
export class AdService {

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

  addAd(ad: InstaAdData): Observable<InstaAdData> {
    return this.http.post<InstaAdData>(`${environment.serviceHost}/ads/ad`, ad, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Thx

Comment: You’ll have to use formData append to post a multi-part form with a file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this that way, thx to MikeOne...

dialog.html -> added enctype

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" enctype="multipart/form-data" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

In my ng-Service I transform InstaAdData to FormData.

```
export class AdService {

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

  addAd(ad: InstaAdData): Observable<FormData> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('config', ad.config.toString());
    formData.append('file', ad.file);
    formData.append('name', ad.name);
    formData.append('price', ad.price);
    formData.append('weekday', ad.weekday);
    formData.append('date', ad.date);
    formData.append('timeWindow', ad.timeWindow);

    return this.http.post<FormData>(`${environment.serviceHost}/ads/ad`, formData);
  }
}
```

I had to remove httpOptions, because that leaded into an error...

And last but not least, my Nest-Controller (this wasn´t part of the question, but maybe it helps others):

```
import { Body, Controller, Post, UploadedFile, UseGuards, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AdsService } from './ads.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { extname } from 'path';

export const imageFileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
    return callback(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
  }
  callback(null, true);
};

export const editFileName = (req, file, callback) => {
  const name = file.originalname.split('.')[0];
  const fileExtName = extname(file.originalname);
  callback(null, `${name}${fileExtName}`);
};

@Controller('ads')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
export class AdsController {

  constructor(private readonly adsService: AdsService) { }

  @Post('ad')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: './uploads',
      filename: editFileName,
    }),
    fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
  }))
  create(@Body() createAdEntity: any, @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File): any {
    this.adsService.create(createAdEntity);

    const response = {
        originalname: file.originalname,
        filename: file.filename,
    };
    return response;
  }
}
```

This is from https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/nestjs-file-uploading-using-multer

Regards